# angular-croppie-module fail to import @type/croppie properly

Tags: angular5, croppie

I'm new to angular 5 and struggling to implement angular-croppie-module in my app.
I tried to have some answer on the module github but without success.
It seems that croppie.directive.d.ts only manage to import the 'Croppie' namespace but not the class.
As a result once I reach the page with the module I get

> ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_croppie___default.a is not a constructor

I created a github repo to show a simple demo of the problem
https://github.com/ErwinSanquer/croppie-demo

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update :

The issue have been fix in version 0.0.6
https://github.com/gatimus/angular-croppie/issues/4

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using angular4 and found croppie pretty easy to work with on its own, and then you can just use the croppie docs to figure out the methods to call. I just did:

npm install croppie

Then created a component to work with it (here is simplified version of the component):

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Croppie } from 'croppie/croppie'; // Reference: http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

@Component({
  selector: 'image-upload',
  templateUrl: './image-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-upload.component.scss']
})
export class ImageUploadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  uploadElement: any;
  croppie: any;
  imageChanged: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initCroppie();
    this.initFileUpload();
  }

  initCroppie() {
    const cropElement = document.getElementById('imageUploadItem');
    this.croppie = new Croppie(cropElement, {
      viewport: { width: 200, height: 200, type: 'circle' },
      boundary: { width: 200, height: 200 },
      enableOrientation: true
    });

    let preloadedImageUrl = Constants.DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMG_URL;

    this.croppie.bind({
      url: preloadedImageUrl,
      zoom: 0
    });
  }

  initFileUpload() {
    this.uploadElement = document.getElementById('fileUploadInput');
    this.uploadElement.addEventListener('change', this.onFileUpload.bind(this));
  }

  onFileUpload() {
    if (this.uploadElement.files && this.uploadElement.files.length > 0) {
      this.imageChanged = true;

      const file = this.uploadElement.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = ((event: any) => {
        this.croppie.bind({
          url: event.target.result
        });
      });
    }
  }

  rotateLeft() {
    this.croppie.rotate(90);
    this.imageChanged = true;
  }

  rotateRight() {
    this.croppie.rotate(-90);
    this.imageChanged = true;
  }

  getCroppieImage(quality: number, numCalls: number): Promise<any> {
    return this.croppie.result({
      type: 'blob',
      size: {
        width: 500,
        height: 500
      },
      format: 'jpeg',
      quality: quality,
      circle: false
    })
      .then((imageDataBlob) => {
        // If image size is still too large just call result again with lower quality
        if (imageDataBlob.size > 500000 && numCalls < 3) {
          quality = quality - 0.1;
          numCalls++;
          return this.getCroppieImage(quality, numCalls);
        } else {
          return imageDataBlob;
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.uploadElement.removeEventListener('change', this.onFileUpload);
  }
}
```

Make sure the template has a div with id='imageUploadItem' for the croppie to live in, and if you let users upload images (like I did in my component above) make sure you have an input with type=file with id='fileUploadInput'.

Comment: I was using angular-croppie and not croppie directly, maybe a bad choice. Anyway angular-croppie have been update to correct the problem. Thank you for your answer.